# Get profile picture from mentions

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to get the profile picture of the person mentioned in the message. I don't even know where to start.

I've tried message.mentions.displayAvatarURL, and some other things I can't find right now, but I'm only able to get my own profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

What you tried gets you close. Try this

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first()

// method 1
const avatar = member.displayAvatarURL()
// method 2
const avatar2 = member.user.avatarURL()
// both get the same image
```

To do it in one line

```js
const avatar = message.mentions.members.first().displayAvatarURL()
```

Please note this will get the first person mentioned be that the bot or whatever so if your command is issued by a mention
`@botName getAvatar @user`
Then this method will return the bots avatar if the that is not `.slice()` from the string.

Comment: I tried method one, I got 

`TypeError: member.displayAvatarURL is not a function`

Comment: Then member wasn’t defined correctly before which is why above that line I defined member

Comment: If you look [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) under methods you will see that `.displayAvatarURL()` is a property of `member`

Comment: I have it setup exactly how you have it, and then I made it so that once someone types "s!user <@mentionhere>" it'll do

`console.log(avatar)`

It's still throwing the error.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your command code so I can get a better picture of what’s going on

Comment: The provided answer shows correct methods, your definition of `member` may not be a valid GuildMember

Comment: At least update the question with the 1 line of code that you use to define `member`